# Using an AND Function in an Array Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to extract some data from a table and, because some of the data is "messy", I can't do a simple `SUMIFS` like I'd normally like to do. 
To get the information I want, I've resorted to using some array formulas. 
I can get most of it working, but I feel like I should be able to combine a couple statements into one and I can't get it to work. 
Here's a simplified version of what my data looks like:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Item** | **Month** | **Qty** |
| 2 | ProductApples123 | January | 101 |
| 3 | ProductApples234 | January | 202 |
| 4 | ProductCherries111 | January | 303 |
| 5 | ProductStrawberries222 | January | 404 |
| 6 | ProductCherries111 | February | 505 |
| 7 | ProductApples345 | February | 606 |

As an example, I want to compute the sum of all the sales of Apples
that happened in January. 
(The desired result for the above data is 303;
i.e., 101+202, for the first two rows.) 
Unfortunately, the name "Apples" is buried
in some other rubbish text that isn't always the same,
so I can't just do this:

```
SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"Apples",B2:B7,"January")
```

The issue is that "Apples" doesn't match what is in column A exactly.

I've resorted to using an array formula and have this:

```
{=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Apples",A2:A7))),C2:C7,"")}
```

That gives me a table that looks like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 202 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 | 606 |

That gives me all the quantities of Apples sold but it doesn't help me with the fact that I want only those that were sold in January. 
I've tried including an `AND()` function in my formula, like this:

```
{=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Apples",A2:A7))),B2:B7="January"),C2:C7,"")}
```

That just gives me an empty list as nothing matches.

So far, what I've been able to do is to create a list of matching items using the first array function and then I combine it with my other list through a `SUMIF` function, like this:

This goes into column G2-G7:

```
{=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Apples",A2:A7))),C2:C7,"")}
```

This formula gives me what I'm after:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B7,"January",G2:G7)
```

If it's not obvious, I don't work with array formulas very often. 
If anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

What I have works, but it just feels odd. I feel like I should be able to condense this down but I'm not sure how.

**EDIT:**

Scott Craner was a big help when he pointed out that I can use wildcards in the `SUMIFS` search. Unfortunately, I had simplified another part of my spreadsheet when I posted it and I'm not sure how to deal with that. I had been focused on the product identification so I removed this complexity because I thought it would be redundant.

In my case, the months aren't listed out the same way I showed,
as simple month names. 
Rather, they are date/time entries, such as "1/3/2022 1:55 PM". I had been using an array formula as shown to get a list of quantities sold if the item matches and then I created another list alongside if that created a yyyy-mm field (e.g., 2022-1). 
Then I used `SUMIF` to add up quantities for each month.

I can use the wildcard search that Scott C. mentioned to identify rows that have matching products – that works great. 
However, I don't know how to use the wildcard with the dates like that. 
I did try using wildcards like this, but it didn't work (I'm assuming you can't use the wildcard in the *middle* of the string):

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"*Apples*",'B2:B7,"*1/*/2022*")
```

This is what my dates actually look like:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Item** | **Month** | **Qty** |
| 2 | ProductApples123 | 1/3/2022 9:21:18 AM | 101 |
| 3 | ProductApples234 | 1/19/2022 4:02:50 PM | 202 |
| 4 | ProductCherries111 | 1/7/2022 4:22:36 PM | 303 |
| 5 | ProductStrawberries222 | 1/12/2022 8:33:49 AM | 404 |
| 6 | ProductCherries111 | 2/10/2022 1:42:15 PM | 505 |
| 7 | ProductApples345 | 2/10/2022 1:37:30 PM | 606 |

Comment: You can use wildcards with SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"*Apples*",B2:B7,"January")`

Comment: But if you want to do differently: `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C7,(ISNUMBER(FIND("Apples",A2:A7))*(B2:B7="January")))`

Comment: Hey Scott - your comment was a big help. Unfortunately, I had simplified part of my problem because I didn't think it was relevant. With your suggestion to use wildcards, though, it suddenly became relevant. :(

I updated the original post to include the details that I had previously glossed over.

Comment: you have to bookend dates: `=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"*Apples*",B2:B7,">=1/1/2022",B2:B7,"<2/1/2022")`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `AND()` doesn’t work in array formulas. 
(I assume it’s more subtle than that,
and I hope somebody will educate me on this.) 
The closest I was able to come to your formula
was to replace `AND()` with `*` (multiplication):

```
=SUM(IF((NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Apples",A2:A7))))*(B2:B7="January"),C2:C7,""))
        ↑                                  ↑⇑↑               ↑
```

but I agree with the other Scott
that `=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"*Apples*",B2:B7,"January")` is a better answer.

---

In response to your assumption (implied rhetorical question)
in the new penultimate paragraph of your question:
Yes, you *can* use a wildcard in the middle of a string. 
But you can’t use string matching techniques against dates.

To demonstrate, here are some data in the same format as yours:

|  | A |  | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Item** |  | **Qty** |
| 2 | cat |  | 1 |
| 3 | cot |  | 2 |
| 4 | dig |  | 4 |
| 5 | dog |  | 10 |
| 6 | city |  | 20 |
| 7 | bandage |  | 40 |

In the following, the second column contains the formula `=SUMIFS(C$2:C$7, A$2:A$7, An)`;
i.e., it uses the search term (criteria)
in the first column of the same row (below)
to search the data above. 
The third column contains a comment.

| Search Term | Formula Result | Comment / Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 1 | Matches row 2, cat |
| dog | 10 | Matches row 5, dog |
| *o* | 12 | Matches rows 3 and 5: cot and dog This is like the "*Apples*" search. |
| c*t | 3 | Matches rows 2 and 3: cat and cot |
| d*g | 14 | Matches rows 4 and 5: dig and dog |
| c*t* | 23 | Matches rows 2, 3 and 6: cat, cot and city |
| d*g* | 14 | Same result as d*g |
| *d*g* | 54 | Matches rows 4, 5 and 7: dig, dog and bandage (which contains "d" followed by "g") |

---

**P.S.** I encourage you to use test data like mine (1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40)
rather than the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 sequence that you used. 
With your data, if you try a formula and it gives a result of 505,
you don’t know whether it came from row 6 (which contains 505),
or from 101+404, or from 202+303. 
With my data, if we get a result of 55,
the only thing it can be is 1+4+10+40.